# Page URL duplicates when clicking link after redirecting

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So let's say if I had a donation page and if you filled payment information and clicked 'submit'. It is going to come up with message saying 'thank you for donation, redirecting to home page' and it redirects in 3 seconds to index page. I have done this by using:

```html
<head>
    <title>HTML Meta Tag</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url = Index" />
</head>
```

I'm using local host to run this web application so when I try to press the links or buttons in index after it has been redirected they don't work.

Allow me to be more specific, when I've started running app, I'm in a page called `https://localhost:5001/` which is the same as my index page.

Now I go to donation page, fill information and submit it. Then coming up with a redirecting message and after that it redirects to index page. However my index web page has now the link of `https://localhost:5001/Home/Index`.

So when I click a separate link or button in that page, it comes with an error. As instead of `https://localhost:5001/Home/Notices/#Welcome`. It is `https://localhost:5001/Home/Home/Notices/#Welcome/` So the links do not work. Please help thanks.

Comment: can you show us the actual a tags you are using?

Comment: @The Abcool: Can you expose a view code that generate the page with the `separate link or button`, please? And perhaps parts of the `RegisterRoutes()` related to the noted URLs.